# How to represent a checkbox with data from two different arrays?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render some check boxes with data from two arrays which are the id and name in one array and the count/length in the other array. Ex:

```
const count = [[{"1":"91"}],[{"1":"1"}],[{"1":"0"}]]
const type = [{id: "1", name: "iPhone"}, {id: "2",name: "Samsung"}, {id: "3",name: "Huawei"}]
```

I tried to use a map function inside another map function.

```
var text=type.map(function(itm,i){
   return [<label key={itm.id}><input type="checkbox" key={itm.id} value={itm.id} name="search"/>{itm.name}</label>, (count && count.length > 0 && count.map( item =>
                      item.length > 0 && item.map( el =>
                          Object.keys(el).length > 0 &&
                          Object.keys(el).map(val => <p>{el[val]}</p>)
                      )
                  )[i])];
}).join(' ');
```

this is how should be represented. [] is the checkbox.

```
[] Iphone (91)
[] samsung (1)
[] huawei (0)
```

the link of the example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6naael

Comment: Is there a reason that compels you to have an array of arrays of objects for count ?
That data structure complexifies the problem in my opinion.

Comment: this is how they got retrieved from the api

Comment: Do you guarantee that in `count` the array that contais an object will only contain one object? Also, whyall  the objects inside `count` have the property name `1` ? Is this always `1` or it can change?

Comment: It will always be 1. it doesn't represent an id or something it is just a name.

Comment: if the 1 in count array doesn't  represent an id, how do you know which count belongs to which item in type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify things by first reducing the array of arrays of object into simple array

```
const { count } = this.state;
const itemCount = count && count.length > 0 && count.map(c => c[0]["1"])
```

Then we just grab the index when we do Array.map() and read from itemCount

```
return (
    <div>
        {type && type.map((type,i) => (
            <label key={type.id}>
                <input 
                    type="checkbox" 
                    key={type.id} 
                    value={type.id} 
                    name="search"
                    onChange={this.handleChange} 
                    onClick={this.handleFilter}/>

                      {type.name}
                      ({itemCount[i]})
                    </label>
                ))}
    </div>
)
```

Working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-184rvv

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the count array and add a new property to type array which holds the total, number of item in count array base on id.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
const count = [[{ "1": "91" }], [{ "1": "1" }], [{ "1": "0" }]]
let type = [{ id: "1", name: "iPhone" }, { id: "2", name: "Samsung" }, { id: "3", name: "Huawei" }]


for (let i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
  Object.keys(count[i][0]).forEach(key => {
    const index = type.findIndex(x => x.id === key);

    const total = parseInt(count[i][0][key], 10);

    type[index].total ? type[index].total += total : type[index].total = total;
  })
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {

    const check = type.map(item => {
      return (
        <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check3"/> {`${item.name} (${item.total ? item.total : 0})`}
        </div>
      )
    })
    return (
      <div>
        {check}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```